# permission denied on www folder

Tags: linux, apache, permissions, permission-denied

I have created a directory in my `www` folder using terminal and `root` user.
Then, create some text files in that folder. (with terminal and `root` user)

Now, when I want to access these files and directory via browser, Apache said:

> 403 Forbidden. You don't have permission to access /folder on this server.

other files and folders in `www` directory are accessible via browser. (I uploaded them via FTP client)

Comment: Have you tried www.example.com or www.example.com/mytextfile.txt? What are the permission currently set? Is there a .htaccess file in place?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the files and folder owner.
Form you terminal:

```
chown YOUR_APACHE_USER YOUR_FOLDER
```

(Obviously you will have to replace YOUR_APACHE_USER and YOUR_FOLDER)

alternatively you can write:

```
chown -R YOURAPACHEUSER YOUR_FOLDER
```

to do all files and sub folders.

Note: you must write the absolute path of YOUR_FOLDER